# Make AJAX request to third party server from MS Office add-in

Tags: jquery, ajax, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get a jQuery GET request out from my Office (Outlook) add-in, but am only getting the error message "Access denied". Documentation is really sparse, or at least hard to find, at this point. Anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much searching, I happened upon the solution by chance. In the file add-in manifest file, there is a tab where one can whitelist domains for requests. Just add the domain in question, and you should be golden.

Comment: It would be useful if you could share some more details of your solution.

Comment: What details do you need? The manifest file is the default one that should be the same in all add-ins.

Comment: @SamStainsby you need to add domain in `<AppDomain>` section in `manifest.xml` file

Comment: @SamStainsby I tried by adding my domain which is in my case https://localhost:7128 with and without port but no luck. Any clues

Comment: @Alireza - I too am facing same issue as Umer any help or reference will help